# Added more parameters to smtplib.SMTP in python

Tags: python, smtplib

Im trying to make a script that sent an email with python using smtp.smtplib , almost of examples i found while googling shows how to call this function with only smtpserver and port parameters.

i want to added other paramaters : domain and binding IP

i tried this : `server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver, 25,'mydomain.com',5,'myServerIP')`
I got this as error : TypeError: **init**() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)

Can you suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is likely because the parameters are invalid (there is one too many). Try looking at the smtplib docs to see what parameters are valid

Comment: I followed the official documentation : smtplib.SMTP(host='', port=0, local_hostname=None, [timeout, ]source_address=None)

Comment: You could try including the "host=" etc. parts, so that Python knows exactly what you mean.

Comment: server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver, 25,'domain.com',5,host='IP')
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'host'

Comment: Try doing that to every parameter. Python usually dislikes it when programmers are inconsistent

Comment: it works without SOURCE_ADDRESS param : server = smtplib.SMTP(
 host = smtpserver,
 port = 25,
 local_hostname='domain.com',
 timeout = 10,
)

Comment: but when i added it : 
server = smtplib.SMTP(
 host = smtpserver,
 port = 25,
 local_hostname='domain.com',
 timeout = 10,
 source_address=('IP')
)

i get this error : 
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'source_address'